# Future indefinite vs future perfect

Tags: tenses

> A total of 9,866 post offices will be turned into e-centres by next year.

Is the above sentence is right? Should it be *will have been turned into e- centres*? So far as I know by next year/by any time refers to future perfect.

Comment: Short answer: Yes, it's correct.

Answer (score 1):

**Either the passive future "...will be turned..", or the passive future perfect "...will have been turned..." are perfectly correct and possible.**

But there is slightly different sense that each conveys. The future simple looks at what will happen in relation to the current point in time. However the future perfect looks at the same thing through the lens of a future moment in time.

**e.g. On Monday I might say: *I will go to Birmingham on Wednesday*. I might also say: *By the time next Saturday arrives, I shall have gone to Birmingham***.

One could equally use either for *I will go to Birmingham by Saturday* or *I will have gone to B by Saturday*.

Sometimes we have an example where both possibilities sound much the same, such as the one you have given.

Comment: In this sentence, by saying by next year, it assures that this turning have been completed when we are in 2018.Isn't it? So, why not using future perfect?

Comment: @AbdulKaiumTanvir as I said, either of them works. But "...will be turned..." looks at the outcome from the current standpoint, whilst "...will have been turned..." sees the outcome through a future lens.

Comment: I have to agree with Abdul here that the future perfect is much better than the simple future. To me, the simple future jars and does not make sense. Your parallel example isn't quite parallel, since it uses _on_ instead of _by_. “I will go to Birmingham by Wednesday” does not sound natural to me either. _By_ in this sense nearly always focuses on the **result** of an action (which is what the perfect aspect denotes), not on the act itself.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Perhaps not as often used, but perfectly grammatical, none the less. A better example might be "I will complete the job by Wednesday".

Comment: I think it's mainly a semantic issue, not a grammatical one. With punctual verbs (especially verbs of finishing), it seems to work all right, though some kind of perfect phrasing is probably still more common. With verbs that describe processes or states, it feels increasingly jarring to me (excluding quite a lot of cases where the verb is _be_, such as “I'll be in London by then”). Going somewhere is more of a process than completing a job, which is punctual; and something like, “I will have fun by Wednesday” is downright bizarre. It's a blurry line, but there is one somewhere.